# Find Similar Branches in multiple Trees

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-theory

Let's say we have N trees, with different sizes and structures. What's the best way to find the similar branches among all those trees? The ultimate goal is find all similar subtrees and sort them from longest similar branches (tree levels) to the shortest one.

[image]

The purpose of question is finding the similar joins among the multiple queries. If we present each query as a tree, the joins makes the branches in each level. And I'm trying to find the similar joins among all the queries.

Comment: Define "similar." Do you mean exact structure? Do you mean that the subtree nodes have the same (or similar, whatever that means) content, regardless of structure? Without a definition of "similar," there's absolutely no way to answer your question.

Comment: I meant EXACT structure by similar.

Comment: Okay, exact structure. Does content matter?

Comment: "Similar subtrees" means the same tree structure as well as the same data.

Comment: You probably should edit your question and add that information. It's rather critical.

Comment: I will. I wonder how can people give negative points to one of the most basic questions in the algorithm. I guess it comes from lack of understanding of the algorithm fundamental knowledge.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I suspect you got that because your question is lacking detail of what you're trying to do, and it doesn't show any effort on your part. I'm not saying that you haven't tried to solve it, but that your question doesn't show us what you've tried. You might consider re-reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: re "similar": in practice, you search for "semantically identical" subtrees, which can have different "similar" representation in the source text (XML, JSON, ...). abstract vs concrete. in "normalization" to the normal form, you also remove redundant whitespace in HTML. use case: in the Nix language: caching the eval result of semantically identical expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by building a map from table name to list of (tree, position in tree). In building this you can find where the same table is referenced twice. Note down where both children of a tree node are leaves.

Visit the places where both children of a node are leaves. Remove these children and their parent from the tree and replace them with a new table name, using the same table name where the two tables just removed are the same. In updating the map you will find out where subtrees of maximum depth 1 are referenced twice in the tree. Note down places where this edit has produced new places where both children of a tree node are leaves.

Repeat the previous paragraph to detect places where, in the original tree, we have identical subtrees of maximum depth 2.

Continue until you have edited all trees into non-existence. You have now found all subtree matches, in reverse order of maximum depth.